# Eiffel exception not work

Tags: exception, rescue, eiffel, post-conditions

I'm trying to use an exception like in the class below, but the program always fails when I call the `kivetel` method. I'd think that it'll just call retry part, than it will satisfy the postcondition. But it fails with "y_above_zero" postcond violation.

```
class
KEYWORDS
create
    make
feature
    y:INTEGER

make
do
end

kivetel
do
ensure
    y__above_zero: y > 0
rescue
    y := 20
    retry
end
end
```

Comment: Is it the exact code you run? I've just checked and it works for me as expected.

Comment: yes this is exactly the code of my class

Comment: I am wondering, do you run it under EiffelStudio ?
if yes, then the debugger will catch the postcondition violation and will popup a dialog to break, continue or ignore.
If you select "continue" the execution should continue without raising again the postcondition.

I've just checked with EiffelStudio 13.11 (but I am sure it is the same with previous releases)

Comment: just downloaded eiffel studio like 4 days ago so I have the newest I think, I click continue than OK no more fail, but is it normal? I thougth it wont drop any error message,beacase the exception part is there

Comment: It would be cleaner to use a conditional, instead of an exception: `kivetel do if y <= 0 then y:=20 end ensure y__above_zero: y > 0 end`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior when you run it under EiffelStudio, i.e under the debugger.
If you run it outside ... from the console for instance, you won't notice anything, the execution will go through the rescue clause and retry and continue as expected.

But under debugger, anytime there is an assertion violation, or an exception, the debugger will catch it and popup the dialog.

(note this is possible to ignore specific kind of exception, if this is really bothering you).

Comment: I would hope there is a way to ignore caught exceptions.

Comment: there is a way from EiffelStudio, to tell the debugger to ignore exceptions.
Manu

Execution> Exception Handling ...

Answer (score 0):

The example shown is not representative for exception handling because of the following reasons:

1. There is *no* exception raised in the `do`...`end` block
2. Routine `kivetel` does nothing, so there cannot be an exception raised
3. The routine `kivetel` is not correct (it does not fulfill the postcondition).

So basically your `rescue` block is not called, because the exception triggered (postcondition violated) is not raised inside the routine.